# Cannot find/access files from previous install of Ubuntu (10.04)

Tags: installation, data-recovery

I've searched for this answer fairly extensively and fruitlessly thus far, mainly I find answers that regard finding Windows files after installing Ubuntu, and a lot of answers regarding Wubi (which I had to google) - I don't think those are relevant to my situation.

My problem;

I can't access my old files from an install of Ubuntu 10.04

I was running 10.04. I upgraded to 12.04 with the updater, It froze up during the process, and I had to reboot. The computer wouldn't boot past the Ubuntu loading screen. I used a Ubuntu install disk of 11.10 to try to get it back on it's feet (and chose to install alongside the failed install of 12.04). That worked, but now I want to figure out how I can access my old files.

Any help, points in the right direction, or anything really vastly appreciated!

edit1: sudo fdisk -l output

```
    sudo fdisk -l 
    Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x000bec1f

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1   *        2048   283774239   141886096   83  Linux
    /dev/sda2       283774974   312580095    14402561    5  Extended
    /dev/sda5       309653504   312580095     1463296   82  Linux swap / Solaris
    /dev/sda6       283774976   307574783    11899904   83  Linux
    /dev/sda7       307576832   309653503     1038336   82  Linux swap / Solaris

    Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Comment: I don't know how to paste a large block of output from terminal into here, so I put it in my post, however, it seems to have lost it's formating.

Comment: Nothing? Well, thank you anyway. I'm sure I'll figure it out eventually.

Comment: Solved. Thanks Tom! I'd upvote your answer if I could but I'm still too new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that's still on the disk should be accessible my mounting the additional partitions. Using Disk Utility you can click on the partitions & mount them (I'm not in front of an Ubuntu system right now, so can't check the exact names/procedure.)

Once the disks are mounted, you should be browse them in the file manager (Nautilus). They'll probably be in the /media/<username>/ folder.